# Check visibility of an element when the element does not appear on the page at all

Tags: javascript

Excuse my naivety. I am a Web Analyst, not so great with Javascript. But, I am steadily learning (I think). Javascript is a fascinating language. So, the following code block appears only when a user triggers a validation error.

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="sisiconfirmemail" data-valmsg-replace="true">
   <span id="sisiconfirmemail-error" class="">The confirmation address and e-mail address must 
   match</span>
</span>
```

Conversely, where a user does not trigger a validation error the code block looks like this:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid icon-ok-sign" data-valmsg-for="sisiconfirmemail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

***Question number 1:*** 
Why the jQuery method, `$('#sisiconfirmemail-error').length > 0` always works when trying to check whether the element `#sisiconfirmemail-error` exists on the page for both code blocks? Why `document.querySelector('#sisiconfirmemail-error').length > 0` only works for the first code block but not for the second?

***Question number 2:***
Is there any pure Javascript method, to check whether an element exists on the page, which would work for code block 1? All my efforts throw a `Cannot read property 'xyz' of null`
I've tried:

```
 1. document.querySelector('#sisiconfirmemail-error').length > 0
 2. document.querySelector('#sisiconfirmemail-error').offsetWidth > 0 &&
    document.querySelector('#sisiconfirmemail-error').offsetHeight > 0
 3. window.getComputedStyle(element).visibility === 'visible';
```

Comment: You need to keep in mind that an element not visible doesn't mean that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check any of the element's property, simply you can check whether returned result is `null` or not by `document.querySelector()`.

```js
if(document.querySelector('.field-validation-error')){
  console.log('element exist');
}
else{
  console.log('element does not exist');
}
```

```html
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="sisiconfirmemail" data-valmsg-replace="true">
   <span id="sisiconfirmemail-error" class="">The confirmation address and e-mail address must 
   match</span>
</span>
```

Comment: So I was making my life difficult by overthinking it. Cheers

Comment: @Greconomist, yap, kind of, still that is also part of learning:)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the **getElementsByClassName(class)** method to get an **HTMLCollection** of elements matching the class. If it's length equals to zero there aren't any.

Here's an example:

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName("field-validation-valid").length > 0) {
  console.log("field-validation-valid exists");
}
```

```html
<span class="field-validation-valid icon-ok-sign" data-valmsg-for="sisiconfirmemail" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 Answer:

You could just check if element exist using

```
if(document.querySelector('#sisiconfirmemail-error'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a check which enables you to return `true` or `false` based on if an element is on the page. Check out this function below which looks for the an element based on your query.

```
const elementExists = selector => document.querySelector(selector) !== null;
```

You can check if both the error and valid message are in the document, or any other element for that matter.

```
const hasErroMessage = elementExists('.field-validation-error');
const hasValidMessage = elementExists('.field-validation-valid');
```

This does not, however, check if the element is visible.